# Android - ClickListener inside ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I create ListView and generate its content with BaseAdapter. The ListView contains Button and hidden ImageView for each row. I put OnClickListener on Button to show ImageView.

Scenario:

- ListView has 9 rows, and 3 rows visible on screen.
- And then I click Button on first row.

Problem:

- ImageView on first row shown successfully, but also on fourth and sixth row.
- It happens also when I click Button on second row. ImageView on fifth and seventh row is shown.

Question:

- Why is that happens? and how to solve it?

This is the code:

- UI Thread

  ```
  .....
  adapter = new ContentAdapter(context, content);
  listView.setListAdapter(adapter);
  .....
  ```
- ContentAdapter

  ```
  .....
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      .....
      final ImageView image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
      ((Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
      });
      .....
  }
  .....
  ```

Comment: Do you use the ViewHolder pattern?

Comment: actually this is not my real code, just write it for same scenario. but yes, i'd use ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: Try to remove the viewholder. If you have only 9 slots you don't need reusability.

Comment: well, that's not the case. my listview will be huge so i need to use viewholder pattern.

Comment: Okay, just give a try to see if the error is on viewholder. Just try it, and if it is, try to improve your view reuse implementation. Just saying.

Comment: Oh, okay, i will try it later and check my viewholder, will give feedback after that. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

do you check for the view if null or something

```
if(view == null)
    view = ((Activity)YourActivity.get()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` handles memory, i.e. it recycles views, it does not create a new view (vonverView in you case) each time, but instead it uses a previously generated view (which is convertView).

So when you scroll you are seeing (for example) row1's view on your newly created row. this is why you see that the image is already shown.

To avoid that you must set your image's visibility to `View.INVISIBLE`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    .....
    final ImageView image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ((Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    .....
}
```

With that, you will not see a visible image when you scroll, ALTHOUGH, if you make row1's image visible, and you scroll down, when you scroll up again you will find row1's image invisible too, in this case you have to save the state of images somewhere (`ArrayList` for example, or a `Map<Integer position, Boolean isvisible>`).

With that being said, you also have to check `ViewHolder Pattern` for adapters, for better memory consumption.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, anyway i didn't tested it yet. but i used View.GONE, what's difference between GONE and INVISIBLE?

Comment: When you use GONE the view is completely gone, meaning the space it takes is gone, INVISIBLE makes it invisible but you can still see the space it takes (something like that)